# How to perform this integration in terms of elementary functions?

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals, radicals, substitution

I need to perform this in tegration in terms of elementary functions... I'm not used to perform integrations like this, so a detailed answer would be very welcome. My integral is the following, 
%
$$
\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{P(x)}} \,\, ,
$$

with

$$
P(x) = \frac{1}{27}-x^{2}(1+2x) \,\, , \qquad x \in \mathbb{R}\,\, .
$$
Once the roots of $P(x)$ are $r_{1}=-1/6$ and the following 2-algebric multiplicity $r_{2}=r_{3} = 1/3$, we can Put the polynomial in the form,

$$
P(x) = 2\left(x +\frac{1}{6}\right)\left(x-\frac{1}{3}\right)^{2} \,\, .
$$

I'm stuck here.

Comment: *Mathematica* gives:  $\frac{-2 (3 x+1) \log (1-6 x)+(6 x+2) \log (3 x+1)-3}{3 x+1}$

Comment: It's wrong because $\sqrt{x^2}\neq x$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the substitution $$x+\frac {1}{6}=t^2$$

For integrals of the form, $$\int \frac{1}{(ax+b) \sqrt{px+q}} \rm dx$$

A standard substitution is $px+q=t^2$

Comment: When I perform this substitution I get $\int dt/(x-1/3)$, I can't get rid of the term which depends on $x$.. Am I dong something wrong?

Comment: Can't you rewrite $x-\frac 13$ in terms of $t$? You already have $$x = t^2 - \frac 16$$

Answer (score 1):

The hint:

Let $$\sqrt{x+\frac{1}{6}}=t.$$

Comment: Isn't it the same?

Comment: @Jaideep Khare  No! I think my hint is more better. In your substitution $t$ can be negative, which is wrong.

Comment: I agree, but we don't take care of these things much when doing indefinite integrals.

Comment: I try to do it. By the way, sometimes it's very interesting.

Comment: BTW, you deserve a +1 for taking care of Mathematics :)